# How to set the size of a newly created TextField without a reference for it

Tags: javafx

My code for creating a Textfield using `new TextField`was used as a parameter for a method like this

```
x.getChildren.addAll(new TextField());
```

My program has a button that creates TextField.

It's a loop to create a number TextFields until the condition is satisfied.
   My own code looks like this:

```
sub.setOnAction(e-> {
    v.getChildren().clear(); //just clearing things
    v1.getChildren().clear(); //just clearing things

    makeStr(Integer.valueOf(numOpt.getText()));
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        v.getChildren().addAll(new Label(list.get(i).toString()));
        v1.getChildren().addAll(new TextField());           
    }   
    list.clear();
});
```

However I cant just change its size like this.

```
v1.getChildren().addAll(new TextField().setPrefWidth(800));
```

Maybe a better code can fix the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you only need to do this in one or 2 locations you do not gain much by writing some code that allows you to do this in a single expression. Simply using a local variable to store the field would be the best way to do this in such a scenario.

```
for(Object element : list){
    v.getChildren().add(new Label(element.toString()));

    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setPrefWidth(800);
    v1.getChildren().add(textField);
}
```

#### Using a method to create & init the field

If you need to create a `TextField` and initialize the `prefWidth` property at the same time in multiple locations in your code, creating a method returning the initialized field would be beneficial.

```
public static TextField createTextField(double prefWidth) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setPrefWidth(prefWidth);
    return textField;
}
```

which allows you write

```
v1.getChildren().add(createTextField(800));
```

instead of

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.setPrefWidth(800);
v1.getChildren().add(textField);
```

To be more flexible when initializing you could also create a builder for `TextField`s.

#### Using a CSS stylesheet

CSS allows you to set properties of multiple nodes at once. You simply need a way to identify the correct nodes to apply a rule to. In this case the rule is applied to all children of `v1` so by adding a style class to this node you can identify the target nodes:

**java**

```
// after creating v1/the scene
v1.getStyleClass().add("v1");
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    v.getChildren().addAll(new Label(list.get(i).toString()));
    v1.getChildren().addAll(new TextField());
}
```

**style.css**

```css
v1>* {
    -fx-pref-width: 800;
}
```

Comment: This made the code simpler and neat. However, Assuming that I created 5 textfields in single click, how can I get the input from the textFields with only one reference for it? 
you can just give me an idea , even without showing the codes sir. I appreciate you response!

Comment: Store them in a custom data structure  or access them using the children of `v1` and cast to `TextField`...

Answer (score 1):

Create reference to every `TextField` you instantiate, set size and then add it to view. Do not use `ObservableList#addAll` method because you are adding only one component. Invoke standard `ObservableList#add` method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    v.getChildren().add(new Label(list.get(i).toString()));
    TextField tf = new TextField();
    tf.setPrefWidth(800);
    v1.getChildren().add(tf);
}
```